# Undefined Index?

Tags: php, post, indexing

I'm working on a very simple, very easy contact form and when i did it on a separate page it worked perfectly, but when i added it to the current website it can't get the $_POST i don't know why. here are the codes

```
$to ="enter email here";
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $header = "From " . $name;
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $content = "From: ". $name ."<br /> Email: " . $email ."<br /> Message: " . $message;

        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            echo "illegal email";
        }
        else
            {
            if (!empty($name) && !empty($message)){
                mail($to, $header, $content);
                echo"sent <br />";
                echo $content;
            }else
                {
                if(empty($email))
                    {
                        echo "your email is empty";
                    }
                    elseif(empty($name))
                    {
                        echo "please enter your name";
                    }
                    elseif(empty($message)){
                        echo "can't send empty messages";
                    }
                }   
            }
```

html

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     Email:
                </td>
                <td>
                     <input type="text" name="email"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     Subject:
                </td>
                <td>
                     <input type="text" name="subject"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Message: <br /><br/><br/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea style="resize:vertical;" name="message"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

thanks in advance and sorry if its a repeat

Comment: Is your PHP code in the mail.php file?

Comment: I guess you know this form is easily used to sent spam by spambots? Your code seems valid to me. @Joe Just to help him out and other persons who read this, not everything is about points.

Comment: @DanBaylis yes it is, its in a include("php/mail.php");

Comment: double check that the form action is pointing to the mail.php script, or that the mail.php script is even being run.

Comment: Agree with @Flosculus - Trying adding: echo "Testing script..." to the top line of your PHP and see if it displays after submitting a form.

Comment: @DanBaylis actually judging from the title of the question 'undefined index' implies that the script is running and the indexes he is selecting dont exist, so im probably wrong with my last suggestion.  Having said that, the error could apply to a different array.

Comment: @Flosculus - That's a good point - I guess it depends whether that is an error actually received, or just their way of describing the $_POST array not being accessible.

Comment: @Baruch what's the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the PHP is actually executing by adding something like this to the top:

```
echo "Testing PHP...";
```

If you do not see that output after submitting a form, check that you are posting the form to the right file.  For example, you might need to use:

```
<form method="post" action="/mail.php">
```

or

```
<form method="post" action="/php/mail.php">
```

...code depending on your website structure.

Comment: Oh! I am sorry dude, I didn't read your comment closely where you mentioned checking the actual path itself... I wasn't trying to hi-jack your comments for answers I promise!

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not $_POST that's broken, so it must be something either server related or an error in your code.

Do you have any other PHP on the website your importing the form to? If so you need to make sure that it isn't affecting it in any way.

One more thing to check, it has been reported that a PHP update accidently changed the upload limit size from "8M" to "10MB". Have a scan through your php.ini file and make sure that their isn't any unwanted "MB" instead of "M" in your upload limit.

One final suggestion I can give if you still haven't found the cause after this, is try using:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

which should reveal what's really there.